# Error in integrate(f): evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length

Tags: r

I am using R to do some multivariate analysis. For this work I need to integrate the trivariate PDF. While doing this I got the error:

```
Error in integrate(Vectorize(function(x) { : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
```

As you could see, vectorize is not the solution so something wrong is going on.

If somebody can give me a hint about what is going on, I'll really appreciate it.

Here is my code:

```
library(mvtnorm)
f1<-function(x, y, z) {dmvnorm(x=as.matrix(cbind(x,y,z)), mean=mu.t, sigma)} #PDF with all three
#integrate out x
integrate(Vectorize(function(x) {f1(x=c1, y=c2, z=c3)}), 0.1,0.5, rel.tol=1.5e-20)$value
```

Comment: What are `c1` , `c2` and `c3`? Please make this [**reproducible**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381)

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell for sure w/out more info on your inputs and outputs, but what's the `length` of the output of `f1`? If it's not the same length as your inputs, I believe that'll cause the error you're getting, as on `integrate` 's  help page:

```
f   an R function taking a numeric first argument and returning a numeric vector of the same length. Returning a non-finite element will generate an error.
```

Comment: I think I figures what was wrong. f1 output is the lenght of the nrow of x (n) and I want a vector of that same length. I did this: for(i in 1:n) {
f1=function(x, y, z) {dmvnorm(x=as.matrix(cbind(x,y,z)), mean=mu.t, sigma=sigma)} 
#Integrate out x
integrate(Vectorize(function(x) {f1(x=c1[i], y=c2[i], z=c3[i])}), lower = -Inf, upper = -xb1[i], rel.tol=1.e-06)$value}
 }